# How to undo a revert action to move back to my previous commit in git

Tags: python, git, github

I ran the revert command to undo my previous commit but then realized I had made a mistake.

How can I undo my revert action and restore to my previously committed state?

Example:

(1) In my project, I have two files A and B and then I committed the changes and push the changes to GitHub.

(2) I added file C and committed changes but didn't push the changes to Github.

(3) I ran the Revert which removed the file C from my project but it was a mistake.

How can I undo my last action of Revert to bring back the file C, which was committed and then reverted on my local repo but never pushed to Github?

Answer (score 1):

> #### Dangit, I did something terribly wrong, please tell me git has a magic time machine!?!
>
> ```sh
> git reflog
> # you will see a list of every thing you've
> # done in git, across all branches!
> # each one has an index HEAD@{index}
> # find the one before you broke everything git reset HEAD@{index}
> # magic time machine
> ```
>
> You can use this to get back stuff you accidentally deleted, or just
>   to remove some stuff you tried that broke the repo, or to recover
>   after a bad merge, or just to go back to a time when things actually
>   worked. I use `reflog` A LOT. Mega hat tip to the many many many many
>   many people who suggested adding it!

Source: https://dangitgit.com/en#magic-time-machine

Answer (score 0):

'git reflog' to list last few HEADS.
Choose commit id of the change you wanted.
git reset to that commit id.